# multiple Input for sales system with javascript and PHP

Tags: javascript, php

Hi all :) i have dificulties in develope my sales system.
in my system i have ItemName,ITem price,qty and total. the problem is every time i want to add new row for new item entry the the price won't appear in item price textbox and calculation for the "total" did not works too. can some one help me to solved my problems.
here is my code
Regards, 
SUGI

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script> 
<title>Untitled Document</title>enter code here
</head>

<body onload="setup()" >
<script  type="text/javascript">

function setup(){
            var itemname = document.getElementById("Item_name");
            var tot = document.getElementById("price"); 

            itemname.onchange = function() {
            var x = document.getElementById("Item_name").selectedIndex;
            var y = document.getElementById("Item_name").options;
            tot.value =  y[x].value;    

                                            }
                 }
function TotalAll(){
    var a=document.getElementById("price");
    var b=document.getElementById("qty");
    var c=document.getElementById("total");
    c.value=a.value*b.value;
}

                 </script>
<table width="871" height="293" border="0">
  <tr>
    <td><form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="">
      <p><strong>SALES </strong></p>
      <table>
             <tr>
          <td>Item Name</td>
          <td>Item Price</td>
          <td>Qty</td>
          <td>Total</td>
         </tr>
</table>
         <table id="dataTable" class="form" border="1">

        <tr>
          <td><select   id="Item_name">
<option value="100">USB Flash Drive</option>
<option value="200">CD ROM</option>
<option value="300">2 GB RAM</option>
<option value="400">1 Tera RAM</option>
<option value="500">Mouse </option>

            </select></td>

          <td><label for="qty"></label>
            <input name="price[]" type="text" id="price" size="2" /></td>
          <td><input name="qty[]" type="text" id="qty"  onblur="TotalAll()"/></td>
          <td><input name="total[]" type="text" id="total"/></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
      <table width="200" border="0">
        <tr>
          <td><input type="button" value="Add Row" onClick="addRow('dataTable')" /> </td>

        </tr>
      </table>

       </tr>
      </table>
      <p>&nbsp;</p>
    </form>

</body>
</html>
```

and here is the code for script.js

```
function addRow(tableID) {
    var table = document.getElementById(tableID);
    var rowCount = table.rows.length;
    if(rowCount < 20){                          // limit the user from creating fields more than your limits
        var row = table.insertRow(rowCount);
        var colCount = table.rows[0].cells.length;
        for(var i=0; i<colCount; i++) {
            var newcell = row.insertCell(i);
            newcell.innerHTML = table.rows[0].cells[i].innerHTML;
        }
    }else{
         alert("Maximum Passenger per ticket is 20.");

    }
}

function deleteRow(tableID) {
    var table = document.getElementById(tableID);
    var rowCount = table.rows.length;
    for(var i=0; i<rowCount; i++) {
        var row = table.rows[i];
        var chkbox = row.cells[0].childNodes[0];
        if(null != chkbox && true == chkbox.checked) {
            if(rowCount <= 1) {                         // limit the user from removing all the fields
                alert("Cannot Remove all the Passenger.");
                break;
            }
            table.deleteRow(i);
            rowCount--;
            i--;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: actually its not updating value of `qty` `textxbox`, if you click on that qty `textbox` and click on `add row` button then its working.

Comment: have try to input new row for new item entry  ?it is working ?

Answer (score 0):

Problem is with your dynamically generated elements. When you are generating new select box, text boxes then all elements have same **ID**. Like when you are generating your price field dynamically then all fields have `id="price"`.

But according to rule in DOM, every element must have an unique id. That's why your *onchange()* event is not working on dynamically generated rows. Do something to generate unique id then this will work.

Comment: ooo isee.ok i'ii try another method :) thanks Deepak